# Can i take tabbar controller in view controller rather than delegate class?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am using a `UINavigation` Controller in a delegate class. After navigating the two views class on the third view class I need a `tabbar` controller which can control three another `ViewControllers` and the tabbar should not be seen on first two view controllers. How can i do this ?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title =@"Scan";

    tabController =[[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    ScanTicketView *scan =[[ScanTicketView alloc]initWithNibName:@"ScanTicketView" bundle:nil];

    SearchView *search =[[SearchView alloc]initWithNibName:@"SearchView" bundle:nil];

    HistoryView *history =[[HistoryView alloc]initWithNibName:@"HistoryView" bundle:nil];

   tabController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:scan,search,history, nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:tabController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Above is the code i am using to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. See this [link to an example](http://ioscoderef.blogspot.com/2012/08/adding-uitabbarcontroller-in.html)

In your second view controller where you want to push to you third view(tab controller) do this

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController,secondViewController,thirdViewController, nil];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];// this works too but since it seems to be against Apple's Human interface Guidelines you can present the view instead of pushing
[self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

Comment: This thing is not working, it is giving error : "[__NSCFConstantString parentViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x98c8"

Comment: Pushing Tabbarcontroller in navigationController is against [Human interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I think this error is related to your code out of the above code i wrote, somewhere you have called something like [self parentViewController]... check it

Comment: @AppleDelegate i just showed him what he wanted. May be his question is against Human interface Guidelines

Answer (score 1):

Follow my answer ... you can add and remove tabBar whenEver you want
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370748/overlay-tabbar-with-a-view/12370879#12370879)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally TabBarcontroller should be the starting case of an app..but in rare cases where you want to present it in a viewcontroller follow ..

```
 UITabBarController *tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstViewController,secondViewController,thirdViewController, nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:NO];
```

Comment: This is my code i am using and control is not going beyond "tabController.viewcontroller" line, it is stucked in a infinilte loop i think.

Comment: Your this code is not working please guide me correct, if you can. Thank you.